# jQuery hover not functioning properly

Tags: jquery

I dont know whats wrong with this Code. The left hover works properly but the right one doesnt. I mean if you Hover on "L" and then you move the mouse to "R" it doesnt work <.

Here is my JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/neoragex/npnHw/5/

Comment: It works properly for me in Chrome.

Comment: Works for me on IE8. Just make sure you don't hover over the `Result` box provided by jsfiddle.

Comment: it work's check that if you made hover in `R` but under the label result of the fiddle works

Comment: Yep, me too Chrome on MAC OS X. Although you might be misled by the blue border, which while hovering on R seems to not move. This is because of your width ( 9999 )

Comment: As @GSerg said, you shouldn't hover over the `Reset` box. It works as expected.

Comment: Can anyone help me improve the code to mimic a carousel? An infiintie carousel where individual elements fade out when its out of the container.

Comment: @LearningSlowly: Better you should post this as a separate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just interfering with the 'Result' label.

Fixed here: http://jsfiddle.net/npnHw/6/

Comment: Yea . I just found that out <.<!~

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in Chrome. Maybe you are using a different browser?

Comment: Oh.Its working for me too :). I kept hovering on the reset button xD. So stoopid of me ^^!~

Comment: happens when we are too nervous!